# Verifying AWS Command Line Interface credentials are configured correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I seem to have problems running a command to verify that my credentials are configured correctly and that I can connect to AWS as stated here:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/tutorial-ec2-ubuntu.html:

When running:

> $ aws ec2 describe-regions --output table

I get the following output:

> An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeRegions
>   operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access
>   credentials

What am I missing?

After [installing the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/tutorial-ec2-ubuntu.html#install-cli) (on a fedora machine), I ran

> $ aws configure

for **AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key**:

1. I went to AWS website and created an IAM user.
2. For that user, I have gone to the security credentials tab and
3. I have created a new Access key, which is key value pair of Access key ID,Secret access key.
   [image]

I have used those values for AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key but I keep getting the above error message.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to pass the `profile` parameter. Refer this link for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

Comment: Thank you, @krishna_mee2004.
If you put that as the answer below, I'll tick it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `profile` parameter. [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html) link from AWS has more details

Comment: You do not **need** to use `--profile`.  I don't understand why this fixes anything.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot, sadly, if I don't pass the --profile parameter, I get the following error: An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeRegions operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials. Am I missing any configuration details?

Comment: @LucasT view/edit your config files manually.  The error seems to imply that you must already have some invalid credentials configured somewhere on your system.