# What is the aws command to verify my login credentials are correct? AKA whoami for aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services

## TLDR

What is the aws-cli command to verify my login credentials are correct?
What is the `whoami` equivalent for the aws-cli?

## Description of problem

I'm learning AWS technologies including serverless and using different accounts when working with different teams.  I sometimes get errors that are due to using the wrong credentials or not having the permission to do something.

When I run into an error, the first thing I want to do is make sure I'm using the correct credentials, so I want a `whoami` command.  So:

1. I want to know that my AWS credentials are valid,
2. What my AWS IAM login is.  The equivalent of `whoami` in Windows or
   Unix.  Obviously, if it just gives me who I am I know I'm valid!
3. What the rights are for the IAM user I'm logged in as.  The IAM roles or permissions this IAM user has.  See also [Roles terms and concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html)

## What I've tried

So I've searched and found:

[Verifying AWS Command Line Interface credentials are configured correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968478/verifying-aws-command-line-interface-credentials-are-configured-correctly) - which again is similar.  It has a link to named profiles which helps by giving me a command that should work `aws ec2 describe-instances` which works, and fills #1 from above list.

More searches give

- [Why am I receiving errors when running AWS CLI commands?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-cli-errors/)

Leads me to: [Why am I receiving the error message "You are not authorized to perform this operation" when I try to launch an EC2 instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-not-auth-launch/) - which I think could help me and answer this question but when I try the command:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.29 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message encoded-message

An error occurred (InvalidAuthorizationMessageException) when calling the DecodeAuthorizationMessage operation: Message is not valid
```

Another link:
[Why can't I run AWS CLI commands on my EC2 instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-aws-cli-commands-ec2/)

which leads me back to a previous link...

I'm guessing that this is a simple request and has a simple answer.  Please share it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use STS [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html):

> Returns details about the IAM user or role whose credentials are used to call the operation.

Run this with awscli, as follows:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Example output:

```json
{
    "UserId": "AIDAAA12345ABCDEFABCD",
    "Account": "123456789012",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/james"
}
```

Comment: +1 also, here's a nice utility for friendly output and some additional info: https://github.com/benkehoe/aws-whoami

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`get-user`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user.html):

```
$ aws iam get-user
{
    "User": {
        "Path": "/",
        "UserName": "myuname",
        "UserId": "...",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/myuname",
        "CreateDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "PasswordLastUsed": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

and [`list-account-aliases`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-account-aliases.html):

```
$ aws iam list-account-aliases
{
    "AccountAliases": [
        "myalias"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This will work if the IAM principal actually has IAM permissions, which is a not a given. The STS get-caller-identity works for all IAM principals, regardless of their permissions.